# difference between grunt-contrib-sass and grunt-sass

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-sass

I am implementing grunt plugin for sass to css processing but there are 2 options are available grunt-contrib-sass and grunt-sass.
I searched on the internet but unable to find any relevant answer that What is the difference between grunt-contrib-sass and grunt-sass, Which one better?

Comment: grunt-sass uses the C++ [libsass](http://sass-lang.com/libsass) and grunt-contrib-sass uses the Ruby [sass](http://sass-lang.com/install). Asking which is better is a primarily opinion-based question and is likely to see this closed as off topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

grunt-sass uses the C++ libsass and grunt-contrib-sass uses the Ruby sass

so it's upto you, you want to use Libsass or Ruby.

Comment: There is also https://github.com/amiramw/grunt-contrib-sassjs which is based on https://github.com/medialize/sass.js, a pure javascript (emscripted libsass) SASS parser.

Comment: I think it is also worth mentioning that grunt-sass is faster since it is based on C++